# Passing value from class to button click event

Tags: c#

I would like to pass `int _iD` to my button click event. For now, I've passed my value to `textbox` and use it in button click. Is there anyway to bypass the `textbox`?

```
public MifarePasswordForm(int _iD)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    int iD = _iD;
    textBox1.Text += iD;
}
```

Button click event

```
private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    byte Oid = Convert.ToByte(textBox1.Text);
}
```

Comment: make a public property and use it.

Comment: you mean change the button click event to public?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a private property if both methods exist in single class else make public property and use it,

```
public int nID;

public MifarePasswordForm(int _iD)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    nID = _iD;
    textBox1.Text += iD;
}
```

Button click event

```
private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    byte Oid = Convert.ToByte(nID);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you currently do is to make your `iD` a local variable (that is, in the method/constructor scope):

```
public MifarePasswordForm(int _iD)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    int iD = _iD; //here it is, the iD is in the constructor/method scope, 
                  //it cannot be accessed outside of the scope
    textBox1.Text += iD;
}
```

You should make your `iD` a `private` field in the **class** scope rather than in the **method** scope:

```
private int iD; //declare here
public MifarePasswordForm(int _iD)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    iD = _iD; //don't declare here
    textBox1.Text += iD;
}
```

So that you can use it like this:

```
private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   byte Oid = (byte)iD;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should declare this variable as class level variable:

```
public class MifarePasswordForm
{
    public int iD {get;set;} // or private field

    public MifarePasswordForm(int _iD)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        iD = _iD; // here you don't create, only use
        textBox1.Text += iD;
    }

    private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //inside this method you can use this variable

       byte Oid = Convert.ToByte(iD);
    }

    //other code
}
```

Now you can use this variable in any method of this class.